Understanding work of PNP transistor


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(circuit has been updated)
I build a simple circuit like this to verify my theorethical understanding of PNP transistor work. What I would like to verify is:

a. when there is no a wire between '-' of the power supply and the
gate, there is no current between emitter and collector

b. when there is a wire to the gate, the current flows through transistor

c. changes in the voltage from the power supply change voltage drop
in different segments of the circuit proportionally


Indeed there is no current between emitter and collector when the gate is closed, however I can't measure current when the gate is opened, despite on my lab power supply shows there is a current in circuit.
Voltage drop in circuit when gate is closed is near 1.7V between emitter and collector, but when gate is opened, the voltage drop is near 0.8V (power suuply is 1.7V). However even I rise up voltage twice more (3.4V), voltage drop between emitter and collector is just 1V -- it is not proportional to changes in power supply and I can't left it to just losses to emittor-collector.
Can you help to understand why do I not register current over multimeter? And why does not voltage change proportionally to the voltage of the power supply?

The base and emitter are shorted and the device will therefore never turn on in this circuit.

@PeterSmith, I drawn not correct diagram. Plus goes to emitter when minus is goes to a collector and a base.

BJTs don't have gates.

The photo doesn't show the power supply, the multimeter or the connections on the underside. Not much use, I'm afraid.

@Transistor, sorry, too much things to put in one photo. If you could rely on my words, power supply connected over resistor to emitter (+) and collector (-), battery over the breadboard is connected to the base (-) and the emitter (+). Bettery supply 3.3V, power supply provides 1.7V

No, sorry. There are too many possible mistakes.

"Gate is closed", "the voltage drop is near 0.8V (power suuply is 1.7V)" The schematic does not show this, so we are all guessing here. Please draw a concise schematic, including node names and refer to them, include any switches/power supplies, meters and whatnot.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Q1's emitter-base junction behaves like a diode in that configuration.
If your voltage source is current limited then the resultant voltage will be 0.7 V or so.
If your voltage source current limit is higher than the b-e junction can tolerate then the e-b junction will fail open-circuit.

I uderstand diode analogy and it would explain drop near 0.7V, but does it also allows voltage drop near 1V? Another question is where is a current which is shown by my lab power supply, but which I can not spot with my multimeter in the circuit. I just used a battery as another source of power supply to replicate this circiut https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/transistor-tran44.gif , but the issue is the same -- lab's power supply detect even higher current, but multimeter shows 0A or 0mA.

Add a clear, nicely cropped photo of your measurement setup. You may have blown the fuse on your multimeter.

Done, but I can not reproduce results of my measurement. There is no current detected by lab's power supply neither by my multimeter between emitter and collector.

Test your multimeter's diode function on a good diode or transistor. Then check your transistor.

Already did, it worked at least yesterday. Right now I have to leave my desk, so if the transistor is OK do we observe abnormal behavior? I mean could you confirm this circuit should work as is and current should be registered by multimeter?

"circuit should work" - what do you expect it to do? It will behave like a diode because that's what it is.
